# Mysql Selecting Max with Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql, max

I have the following structure:

```
Attended:
  id
  user
  date


Meetings:
  id
  data
  place

Places
  id
  name

users
  id
  name
```

I'm trying to get the maximum date the user attended the meeting and i'm able to do this by running the following:

```
select (meetings.date), places.name, meetings.id, attend.user
from attend
    inner join meetings on meetings.Id = attend.meeting 
    inner join places on meetings.place = places.id
WHERE meetings.date IN (select max(meetings.date) from meetings)
```

However, only the date will be correct, if i try to print out the name of the place it will not be the place that is associated with the meeting with the max date but it actually prints the place with first row that i get from the attend table.

What is the best approach to finding the max attended date based on the meeting date?

Comment: Your query should be returning all users who attended meetings on the most recent date that had a meeting.  I can't tell if this is what you actually want, though.

Comment: Yes, that is what i actually want, and i do get that but place name would return the incorrect information.  Like if my last attend was a meeting 1 which is for place A, but my first attend was for meeting 2 which is Place B, then the query will print place B instead of A

Comment: A good way to select a row where one of the columns is a maximum (or minimum) is to order by it and limit your result set: `ORDER BY meetings.date DESC LIMIT 1`. I'd post this as an answer but based on your question I'm not completely sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you please correct either your table structure or your query to match table and column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT a.user_name, a.meeting, a.place_name, a.date 
  FROM 
(
  SELECT a.user, a.meeting, m.date, p.name place_name, u.name user_name
    FROM attended a JOIN meetings m
      ON a.meeting = m.id JOIN places p
      ON m.place = p.id JOIN users u
      ON a.user = u.id
) a JOIN 
(
  SELECT a.user, MAX(m.date) date
    FROM attended a JOIN meetings m
      ON a.meeting = m.id
   GROUP BY user
) q 
    ON a.user = q.user
   AND a.date = q.date
 ORDER BY user_name
```

Sample output:

```
| USER_NAME | MEETING | PLACE_NAME |                          DATE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    User 1 |       2 |    Place 2 | August, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|    User 2 |       1 |    Place 1 |   July, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|    User 3 |       1 |    Place 1 |   July, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d766f/4)** demo